# When I click on the TextView the application closes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my application I am trying to click on the text view and redirect it to another location. But after opening the application, when I click on the text view, my application closes. Where am I making the mistake? Can you help me?

MainActivity;

```
txt_kayitsayfasinagit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,KaydolActivity.class));

        }
    });
```

TextView;

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_kayitsayfasinagit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hesabin_yok_mu_kaydol"
    android:textColor="#B2B2B2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_giris"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.10" />
```

Manifest;

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Picker">
    <activity android:name=".KaydolActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AnaSayfaActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/background_splash" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbvZ6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m9Hi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COj3n.png)

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/115145

Comment: It closes because there's probably an exception occurring somewhere. It would help if you posted your logcat as well

Comment: add full mainactivity code to the question

Comment: first you need to understand whether the app is crashing or not. then, Where is it crashing? in the main activity or the KaydolActivity activity. and then share the code to the activity that crashes.

Comment: As you said, I installed logcats, you can look at the photos.

Comment: The problem is that you Can not cast a MaterialTextView to an EditText, I guess you wanted to cast it to TextView, so check if this is the problem.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initialize the EditText first, like this:**

```
EditText text;

text = findViewById(R.id.txt_kayitsayfasinagit);
```

**then add listener for the text, like this:**

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,KaydolActivity.class));

        }
    });
```

Comment: I did the way you said, but I get an error, I added it as a photo. You can check the error I received above. The error it gives is fixed when I do "EditText" from "activty_main.xlm" to "TextView", this time when I click on it the text is written and it closes again.

Comment: Brother make sure that you are casting EditText both in activity and XML in same version.

either use Material EditText on both case. Or use Androidx Compat EditText

Comment: I've checked everything but unfortunately can't fix the error. There is a "sign up" text on my login screen. I'm trying to be directed to the "sign up" page by clicking it, but I still haven't succeeded.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not seeing any mistakes in your code. Is the MainActivity code properly inside the onCreate() or onStart() method?
A good tip is to look at the logcat to see the error message.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: I have installed logcat right now, can you check it again?